# Buscar el nombre de la persona de mayor edad

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hola a tod@s tengo este código escrito para resolver este ejercicio, quisiera saber como puedo finalizar el ejercicio, especificamente, me refiero a como puedo almacenar el nombre de la persona con mayor edad. Cabe mencionar soy un principiante en esta área y estoy aprendiendo los ciclos for y while, por ende, rogaría que fuera resuelto así, puesto que, vi una forma de resolverlo con esta función `nombre_mayor_edad = nombres[edades.index(max(edades))]` y no entendí bien, que es lo que hace en definitiva, si pudieran orientarme o explicarme cqué es lo que hace, agradecería de antemano.

---

```
nombres = []
edades = []

n = int(input("Cantidad de personas: "))

while len(nombres) < n:
    nombre = input("Ingrese nombre: ")
    edad = int(input("Ingrese edad: "))
    nombres.append(nombre)
    edades.append(edad)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO es te invito a que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y que leas [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: El código que dijiste que no sabías que es lo que hacía pues hace lo siguiente; ```edades.index()``` obtiene el índice de lo que está adentro de los paréntesis en el arreglo de edades, con ```max(edades)``` obtienes el número mayor del arreglo edades, eso es lo que querías?

Answer (score 0):

```
Básicamente esto es lo que hace la función:
max(edades)->te busca la máxima edad del arreglo de edades,
edades.index(max(edades))->luego te consigue la posicion(numero) de esa maxima edad.
nombres[edades.index(max(edades))]->con esa posicion que obtuviste que se queda dentro del corchete, el vector la asocia con un valor respectivo.
nombre_mayor_edad = nombres[edades.index(max(edades))]->al final el nombre que tiene la mayor edad lo guardas en la variable nombre_mayor_edad.
Nota: Recuerda que se accede a los valores de los vectores por medio de respectivas posiciones.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nombres = []
edades = []

n = int(input("Cantidad de personas: "))

while len(nombres) < n:
    nombre = input("Ingrese nombre: ")
    edad = int(input("Ingrese edad: "))
    nombres.append(nombre)
    edades.append(edad)

mayorEdad = max(edades)
mayorEdadNombre = nombres[edades.index(mayorEdad)]
print("La persona de mayor edad se llama", mayorEdadNombre, "y tiene", mayorEdad, "años")
```

En `mayorEdad` almacenas la edad máxima de la lista `edades`. En `mayorEdadNombre` almacenas el valor de la lista `nombres` que se encuentra en la misma posición que la máxima edad en `edades`.